# I want to make something that i do not know what to call

Tags: java, processing

I'm not sure what to say, i am new to coding and and i want to do something. I think the easiest way to tell you is to "show" you what i want to do.

```
// this is how I want something to look like

void method() {
  println(something.somestring1);
  println(something.somestring2);
  println(something.someint);
}

// this is where I want to make something that allows me to do what I just showed you.

void something() {
  String somestring1 = "hello";
  String somestring2 = "bye";
  int someint = 10;
}

// this should then print:

// hello
// bye
// 10
```

I dont know if what i want to do is even possible or if it has a name.
If this is impossible and there is something similar that is working, then please tell me.
I can live without this but it would make some things much easier.

I am coding in processing 3

Comment: `something` should be a class, not a method, and your code would work.

Comment: What you are searching for is called `class`.

Comment: I would recommend taking a beginner course. The very first examples will probably already teach you how to do this. This is like first week Java, a very basic class with some simple fields and methods.

Comment: @Nicktar Please consider [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts. Read the tag-info <[processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info)>!

Comment: @Zabuza The question is not about native java. It is about [Processing](https://processing.org/). Yes I know "processing" is misleading and often understood more general than it is.

Comment: @Rabbid76 TIL processing is a thing... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are searching for is called [`class`](https://processing.org/reference/class.html).

Create a `class Somthing` with the attributes `somestring1`, `somestring2` and `someint`:

```java
class Something
{
    String somestring1 = "hello";
    String somestring2 = "bye";
    int someint = 10;

    Something() {
    }
}
```

Create an instance of the class:

```java
void setup() {
  Something something = new Something();

  println(something.somestring1);
  println(something.somestring2);
  println(something.someint);
}
```